# Replace element in PHP array with new text if specific text exist already

Tags: php, arrays

Looking at the php documentation is not very clear as to how I can replace the contents of a single element in an array with new string if the first single element contains specific text. In other words, if my array contains `#ff0000` in the 'color' element then replace `#ff0000` with the word `RED`

```
$data = "[{"name":"Bowie Hospital Center","time":["","",""],"color":[false,false,false]},{"name":"Calvert Memorial Hospital","time":["","","",""],"color":[false,false,false,false]},{"name":"Charles Regional (UM)","time":["","","",""],"color":[false,false,false,false]},{"name":"Doctors Community Hospital","time":["","","",""],"color":[false,false,false,false]},{"name":"Fort Washington Hospital","time":["","","",""],"color":[false,false,false,false]},{"name":"Germantown EC","time":["","",""],"color":[false,false,false]},{"name":"Holy Cross Germantown","time":["","","",""],"color":[false,false,false,false]},{"name":"Holy Cross Hospital","time":["","","",""],"color":[false,false,false,false]},{"name":"Laurel Regional Medical Center","time":["","09:20","",""],"color":[false,"background-color:#ff0000;color:#000000;",false,false]},{"name":"Malcolm Grow","time":["","",""],"color":[false,false,false]},{"name":"Montgomery Medical Center (MedStar)","time":["","","",""],"color":[false,false,false,false]},{"name":"Prince Georges Hospital Center","time":["","","","",""],"color":[false,false,false,false,false]},{"name":"Shady Grove Advent Hospital","time":["","","",""],"color":[false,false,false,false]},{"name":"Southern Maryland Hospital\u00a0 (MedStar)","time":["","","",""],"color":[false,false,false,false]},{"name":"St. Mary\u2019s Hospital\u00a0 (MedStar)","time":["","","",""],"color":[false,false,false,false]},{"name":"Suburban Hospital (JHM)","time":["","","","",""],"color":[false,false,false,false,false]},{"name":"Walter Reed NMMC","time":["","","","",""],"color":[false,false,false,false,false]},{"name":"Washington Adventist Hospital","time":["","","",""],"color":[false,false,false,false]},{"name":"Childrens National Medical Center","time":["","","","",""],"color":[false,false,false,false,false]},{"name":"George Washington Hospital","time":["","","","",""],"color":[false,false,false,false,false]},{"name":"Georgetown University (MedStar)","time":["","","",""],"color":[false,false,false,false]},{"name":"Howard University Hospital","time":["","","","",""],"color":[false,false,false,false,false]},{"name":"MedStar Washington Hospital Center","time":["10:09","","","",""],"color":["background-color:#ffff00;color:#000000;",false,false,false,false]},{"name":"Providence Hospital","time":["","","",""],"color":[false,false,false,false]},{"name":"Sibley Memorial Hospital (JHM)","time":["","","",""],"color":[false,false,false,false]},{"name":"United Medical Center","time":["10:09","10:09","",""],"color":["background-color:#ffff00;color:#000000;","background-color:#ff0000;color:#000000;",false,false]}]";
$json = json_decode($data, true);
myArray($json);

function myArray($arry) {
    foreach($arry as $key => $value) {
        $result .= $value['name']. chr(10);
            $length = count($value["color"]);
            for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
                if($value['time'][$i] != "") {

                    if(in_array('background-color:#ff0000;color:#000000;', $value['color'][$i])) {
                        $value['color'][$i] = 'RED';
                    }

                $result .= $value["color"][$i] . chr(10) . $value["time"][$i] . chr(10) . chr(10); 
                }
            }
    }
    return $result;
}
```

EXAMPLE DATA:

```
[{"name":"Bowie Hospital Center","time":["","",""],"color":[false,false,false]},{"name":"Calvert Memorial Hospital","time":["","","",""],"color":[false,false,false,false]},{"name":"Charles Regional (UM)","time":["","","",""],"color":[false,false,false,false]},{"name":"Doctors Community Hospital","time":["","","",""],"color":[false,false,false,false]},{"name":"Fort Washington Hospital","time":["","","",""],"color":[false,false,false,false]},{"name":"Germantown EC","time":["","",""],"color":[false,false,false]},{"name":"Holy Cross Germantown","time":["","","",""],"color":[false,false,false,false]},{"name":"Holy Cross Hospital","time":["","","",""],"color":[false,false,false,false]},{"name":"Laurel Regional Medical Center","time":["","09:20","",""],"color":[false,"background-color:#ff0000;color:#000000;",false,false]},{"name":"Malcolm Grow","time":["","",""],"color":[false,false,false]},{"name":"Montgomery Medical Center (MedStar)","time":["","","",""],"color":[false,false,false,false]},{"name":"Prince Georges Hospital Center","time":["","","","",""],"color":[false,false,false,false,false]},{"name":"Shady Grove Advent Hospital","time":["","","",""],"color":[false,false,false,false]},{"name":"Southern Maryland Hospital\u00a0 (MedStar)","time":["","","",""],"color":[false,false,false,false]},{"name":"St. Mary\u2019s Hospital\u00a0 (MedStar)","time":["","","",""],"color":[false,false,false,false]},{"name":"Suburban Hospital (JHM)","time":["","","","",""],"color":[false,false,false,false,false]},{"name":"Walter Reed NMMC","time":["","","","",""],"color":[false,false,false,false,false]},{"name":"Washington Adventist Hospital","time":["","","",""],"color":[false,false,false,false]},{"name":"Childrens National Medical Center","time":["","","","",""],"color":[false,false,false,false,false]},{"name":"George Washington Hospital","time":["","","","",""],"color":[false,false,false,false,false]},{"name":"Georgetown University (MedStar)","time":["","","",""],"color":[false,false,false,false]},{"name":"Howard University Hospital","time":["","","","",""],"color":[false,false,false,false,false]},{"name":"MedStar Washington Hospital Center","time":["10:09","","","",""],"color":["background-color:#ffff00;color:#000000;",false,false,false,false]},{"name":"Providence Hospital","time":["","","",""],"color":[false,false,false,false]},{"name":"Sibley Memorial Hospital (JHM)","time":["","","",""],"color":[false,false,false,false]},{"name":"United Medical Center","time":["10:09","10:09","",""],"color":["background-color:#ffff00;color:#000000;","background-color:#ff0000;color:#000000;",false,false]}]
```

Comment: Please add an example array to demonstrate your data.

Comment: done - this is sample data of all array / json data I'm using from remote sourse.

Comment: $value['color'][$i] = 'RED';

Comment: that doesn't work. I've looked at case sensitive in the `in_array` but can't find anything wrong - is there a way to see if array contains... partial text as opposed to exact match?

Comment: That does _not_ look like an array. Not at all.

Comment: its JSON before its decoded into array. - same data

Comment: That is a json encoded array holding _objects_. You cannot simply iterate object properties by a for loop.

Comment: its working fine with existing code and returning results, just not replacing hex with the matching color.

Comment: No, it does not. It clearly throws warnings for each loop iteration just as expected: `PHP Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in ...`

Comment: updated question to include code of json conversion...at top

Comment: let's say it work in your side, instead of if(in_array.... try with a simple regex : if(preg_match('/#ff0000/', $value['color'][$i]))

Comment: that worked, thanks, not sure why the `in_array` was not working???

Comment: Hmm not sure too but for match some part of a pattern, better to use the regex (please mark my answer if it was any help to you)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of

```
if(in_array('background-color:#ff0000;color:#000000;', $value['color'][$i]))
```

try with a simple regex :

```
if(preg_match('/#ff0000/', $value['color'][$i]))
```